# Can't inject multiple ObjectMapper beans in Spring Boot application

Tags: jackson, spring-boot

I am defining beans using @Bean annotation and trying to wire them using name , but receiving an exception.

**Complete Example**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.example"})
public class SampleSpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper scmsObjectMapper() {
        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper responseMapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
        return responseMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper scmsWriteObjectMapper() {
        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper responseMapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
        return responseMapper;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping(method={RequestMethod.GET}, value="sample/hello", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> getCart() {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello", HttpStatus.OK);
    }


}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.7.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
        classpath('io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' 

jar {
    baseName = 'Sample-SpringBoot'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.3.RELEASE")
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.1')
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.7'
}
```

Exception

```
 Caused by:
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
 qualifying bean of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]
 is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2:
 scmsObjectMapper,scmsWriteObjectMapper
```

Comment: Sorry Nir , it was a typo when I typed here. I am using the correct qualifier in my code.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please post a complete example.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis , posted the complete example. The server is not even starting , I get an error after I click run as spring boot app.

Comment: I don't see you manually injecting the `ObjectMapper` anywhere.

Comment: Yes , i just excluded it for now as the Bean definition itself is causing server to not start.

Comment: What does this have to do with `@Qualifier` then?

Comment: I defined @Qualifier to autowire by name. But I removed that and figured out that the bean definition itself is returning this error. I have pasted the error too.

Comment: Then this a completely different question. Please edit to remove any mention of `@Qualifier`. This has nothing to do with it.

Comment: And truncate the stack trace.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis , made the changes..

Comment: @M. Deinum, Thanks for formatting. Will format this way in future.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By default, Spring Boot defines a bean of type `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and tries to inject an `ObjectMapper` into it. This typically allows you to simply declare an `ObjectMapper` `@Bean`, configure it any way you need to, and have Spring Boot do the rest for you.

Here, this has backfired because you declare two of them.

One solution, [as described in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper), is to annotate the `@Bean` definition of the one you want injected as `@Primary`.

> If you want to replace the default `ObjectMapper` completely, define a
>   `@Bean` of that type and mark it as `@Primary`.

For example,

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper scmsObjectMapper() {
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper responseMapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
    return responseMapper;
}
```

Spring Boot will use that one.

Alternatively, you can declare your own `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` bean definition and configure everything internally. From the same documentation

> Finally, if you provide any `@Bean`s of type
>   `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` then they will replace the default
>   value in the MVC configuration.

For example (taken from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/customizing))

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return jsonConverter;
}
```